# Check if a complex scope variable was modified in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Complex scope variable, something like the following.

```
$scope.ComplexVariable={
      PrimaryObjOne:{
         SecondaryOne:'',
         SecondaryTwo:''
      },
      PrimaryObjTwo:{
         SecondaryOne:'',
         SecondaryTwo:''
      }
}
```

Is there any clean way to check if any of the properties(at the secondary level in my example) associated with this object were modified. Adding a $watch against each property would work, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.$watch("ComplexVariable", function (oldVal, newVal) {
}, true);
```

The true at the end will watch the entire object for any changes.

Comment: This helps. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to [`$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) allows you to compare objects using object equality rather than reference equality (which is the default).

```
function objectChanged() {
  // ...
}

var useObjectEquality = true;

$scope.$watch('ComplexVariable', objectChanged, useObjectEquality);
```

This makes use of [`angular.equals`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) rather than `==` or `===`.